# Check each object in a ArrayList for itself

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, boolean, sprite

In a game that I'm working on I have implemented some powerups. I want the powerups to spawn at the same place as the zombie that you killed died on.

I spawn all the zombies with a `ArrayList` so therefor when I kill a zombie I have to spawn the powerup at that zombies location and not any other zombies location. I got this code in a `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method (zombies is the `ArrayList`).

```
for(int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++){
        Zombie z = (Zombie) zombies.get(i);
        if(!z.isAlive()){
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("Health.png");
            image = ii.getImage();
            g2D.drawImage(image, (int) z.getX(), (int) z.getY(), this);
            System.out.println("Zombie state: " + z.isAlive());
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I kill a zombie it wont spawn the health pack at that zombies location (It wont spawn it at any other zombies location either). If I remove the `!` in the if-statement a health pack will be drawn inside all of the zombies so I know that it should spawn the health pack at the right location.

It only print out the text "Zombie state: false" once so it have something to do with when it checks if the zombie is alive or not (probably that it only counts as `z.isAlive` is false when all zombies are dead).

`isAlive` in `Zombie` is only a boolean that equals to true as default and I have set it to equal false if you shoot a zombie with this if-statement. How would I check each zombie if it's alive (which I was pretty sure that I already had done because when one zombies health equals to 50 only that zombie dies and not all of them)?

```
if(z.getHealth() == 50) z.setAlive(false);
```

Comment: Unrelated to your actual questions, but if you use `ArrayList<Zombie>` you can avoid the dangerous cast and use `Zombie z = zombies.get(i);`.

Comment: Shouldn't `Zombie.isAlive` always return false? I mean, they're all dead...

Comment: As a basic piece of pattern advice, I'd recommend the use of either an `iterator` or an enhanced for loop here. Also, why do you have to cast back to `Zombie` after the get out of the `ArrayList`? Is it an `ArrayList<SomeSuperClazz>`?

Comment: That is what I was asking after.

Comment: You should generally not load the same file multiple times. Load the health image once, and store it in a variable. This makes your program run faster. Also, I don't know what your `Zombie` class looks like, but it sounds like it has some static methods and/or fields that shouldn't be static.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way to deal with scenario like this is .. how and when is the health is reduced. so why don't you create the image wherever it is that you are using this statement

```
if(z.getHealth() == 50) z.setAlive(false);
```

to

```
if(z.getHealth() == 50){
    z.setAlive(false);
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("Health.png");
    image = ii.getImage();
    g2D.drawImage(image, (int) z.getX(), (int) z.getY(), this);
    System.out.println("Zombie state: " + z.isAlive());
}
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't do draw operations outside the `paintComponent` method.

Comment: When I do that the image appears for a split second and then disapears again